# While installing cloud manager facing oracle-j2sdk1.7 installation failed

Tags: oracle, ubuntu

im trying to install cloud manager on ubuntu 12.04.

But im failed and below is the error :

oracle-j2sdk1.7 installation failed. See /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/3.install-oracle-j2sdk1.7.log for details. Click OK to revert this installation.

Any help can be appricaited now.

Regards,
BJ

Comment: We really need to know whats in the contents of the log. Your error message says exactly that. Please provide the full log in your original post.

Comment: im now getting this error .See /var/log/cloudera-manager-installer/2.refresh-repo.log for details. Click OK to revert this installation.

Comment: E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

Comment: i tried more than 50 times.....give me the exact answer....

Answer (score 1):

Looks like its some kind of lock already in place which might occur at login or because of the first attempt at the installation failing.

Try logging in, maybe even rebooting and trying again.

If this still fails, try the following:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf 
sudo apt-get update
```

This should force an update and recreate the directory correctly. There's a thread about this on the Ubuntu forums which might be more useful and provide a lot more information on this problem:

http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1986288

If this is still a problem. Provide the full stack trace/log that is mentioned in the error.

We can't blindly provide advice, we need the actual error from the log in order to help you.